# windows 8 ui all windows blurred, icons at random size(as well as toolbars)

Tags: windows-8

after i started using hdmi a lot(connecting and diconnecting), my icons in tabskbar and desktop become different sizes, all windows blurred, flash player content very small.

Does anybody know how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [disable the DPI scaling options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2900023).

These are enabled by default in newer versions of Windows.

> Disable DPI virtualization for the application. To do this,
> right-click the application’s shortcut and then click Properties. On
> the Compatibility tab, select Disable Display Scaling On High DPI
> Settings, and then click OK.
>
> This causes the text in the application
> to appear clearer. However, if the application does not correctly
> handle high DPI settings, this procedure may have adverse side effects
> such as truncated text and incorrectly sized graphical elements. Lower
> the overall Windows DPI setting. To do this, open the Display item in
> Control Panel (or search for "dpiscaling" from the Start screen), and
> then adjust the slider under Change the size of all items. You may
> have to click to select the check box for Let me choose one scaling
> level for all my displays and then change the scale to 100 percent.
>
> Be aware that on very high-DPI displays, this may make screen elements
> very small, and some text may become difficult to read.

Comment: i need to unblur all aplications and normalize taskbar icon size

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: 8.1, not really me

Comment: See this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2900023

Comment: what about toolbar?